# Connecting to my server through SSH using Terminal - permission denied

Tags: ssh, server, passwords

I am trying to get access to my server via SSH using Terminal.

I have created a key in cPanel which required me to set a password. I'm trying to connect in Terminal using this password but it says Permission Denied.

I am trying connect by doing:

```
 ssh mysite.co.uk
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is your user name the same on both machines?

Comment: no. my default in Terminal is doing mymacusername@mysite.com how can i change that?

Comment: Just do `ssh your_remote_username@mysite.co.uk`

Comment: I don't think my provider has enabled it. have switched servers and done what you said and its fine now. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using following format:

```
ssh <Your user>@mysite.co.uk
```

Make sure that your user has correct right to connect via SSH.

Answer (score 0):

Server wasn't SSH enabled properly. Switched servers to another provider and did:

```
 ssh your_remote_username@mysite.co.uk
```

works fine.